# How to deal with tab, newline characters and different kinds of slashes in filenames (python)?

Tags: python, string, path

I'm trying to read pathnames from the user and joining new directories to it. The problem is that the path string has directories starting with "n" or "t", which gives inconsistencies when parsing.
My OS in Windows 10, and my Python version is 3.7.6.
The supplied argument to argparse is `'C:\\Codes\\timpel\\noiseAnalysis\\Metadata'`

```
import os
from argparse import ArgumentParser
def main(args):
    case_name = 'APP001'
    file_name = 'APP001.json'
    input_path = args.input_dir 
    output_file = os.path.join(
        args.input_dir,
        case_name,
        file_name
    )

    print(input_path)
    print(output_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input_dir', type=str)
    main(parser.parse_args())
```

The printing results are `C:\\Codes\\timpel\\noiseAnalysis\\Metadata` and `C:\\Codes\\timpel\\noiseAnalysis\\Metadata\APP001\APP001.json` respectively.

How should I deal with this type of problem consistently? How should I deal with different types of slashes in the pathname given by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I needed to change some erroneous variable names, but if you call the program on the command line with:

`C:\>prog.py C:\Codes\timpel\noiseAnalysis\Metadata` it outputs:

```
C:\Codes\timpel\noiseAnalysis\Metadata
C:\Codes\timpel\noiseAnalysis\Metadata\APP001\APP001.json
```

At least in my version of Python (3.6). Code:

```
import os
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def main(args):
    input_path = args.input_dir      # <--
    case_name = 'APP001'
    file_name = 'APP001.json'

    output_file = os.path.join(
        input_path,
        case_name,
        file_name
    )

    print(input_path)
    print(output_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input_dir', type=str)
    main(parser.parse_args())
```

Comment: what if the string is supplied by an outside user?

Comment: I suppose, it would largely depend on *how* the string is provided. If you allow the user to specify `'\u'` as part of the string, you essentially get the unicode character and there is little you can do about it then. Note that `input_path = input('')` takes the string as a raw string in Python 3.

Comment: When the user specifies the path as a command line option, it neither should be a problem. And neither is it a problem when the path is specified from file. When does this occur in your case?

Comment: The path is supplied as a argument from ```argparse.ArgumentParser()``` as a string.

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps your question or maybe somebody coming here for `argparser`-ing Windows path problems, but I found a bug in IDLE that strips backslashes entered in "Run... Customized".  This DOES NOT happen when running from the command line.

When you enter `C:\Codes\timpel\noiseAnalysis\Metadata` into `Run... Customized` in IDLE it becomes`C:CodestimpelnoiseAnalysisMetadata`, but works just find on the command line (e.g.:`python prog.py C:\Codes\timpel\noiseAnalysis\Metadata`)

There is a work-around for IDLE.  If you entered the path in quotes (e.g.:`'C:\Codes\timpel\noiseAnalysis\Metadata'`) it will be processed fine.

Also note that backslashes `\` in IDLE arguments cause the pre-populated textbox to get screwed up even if you use the quotes work-around.  The text that was passed to the previous run will now be surrounded in curly braces (e.g.:`{C:CodestimpelnoiseAnalysisMetadata}`).

I filed an [issue on github](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/93016) for this and I'm waiting for a response.